# monotone convergence thrm, unbounded sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, monotone-functions

Show that if $(x_n)$ is unbounded, then there exist a subsequence $\left(x_{n_{k}}\right)$ such that $\lim(\frac{1}{x_{n_{k}}}) = 0$.

By the monotone converge theorem if $X$ converges there exists a subsequence that's either increasing or decreasing.

**Case 1 (increasing):** Since $X$ is increasing $x_{n_{1}}$ > $x_{n_{2}}$ > ... > $x_{n_{k}}$. Since $X$ is unbounded its subsequence is also unbounded, and therefore approaches infinity. Therefore the reciprocal $\frac{1}{x_{n_{1}}}$ > $\frac{1}{x_{n_{2}}}$ > ... > $\frac{1}{x_{n_{k}}}$ goes to $0$.

**Case 2 (decreasing):** Since $X$ is decreasing $x_{n_{1}}$ < $x_{n_{2}}$ < ... < $x_{n_{k}}$. Since $X$ is unbounded its subsequence is also unbounded, and therefore approaches negative infinity. Therefore the reciprocal $\frac{1}{x_{n_{1}}}$ > $\frac{1}{x_{n_{2}}}$ > ... > $\frac{1}{x_{n_{k}}}$ goes to $0$.

Is this proof sufficient? Is there a better way to show it, or do it?

Comment: No. It is wrong. If $X$ is convergent, then it is bounded. Then, you can't apply the theorem as you are trying

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue like this.

Since $(x_n)$ is unbounded, there has to be some term $x_{n_1}$ so that $| x_{n_1} | \geq 2$. Inductively suppose we've picked the indices $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_{k-1}$. Given $k$, again because $(x_n)$ is unbounded, we can find an $n_k > n_{k-1}$ so that

$$ \left\vert x_{n_k} \right\vert \geq 2^k $$

Now if you want to show formally that

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x_{n_k}} = 0 $$

then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, pick $K$ such that $2^{-K} < \varepsilon$, and note that

$$ \begin{align*}
| 1 / x_{n_k} | & \leq 2^{-k} \\
& \leq 2^{-K} \\
& < \varepsilon
\end{align*} $$

for all $k \geq K$.